# Interpolating on a 2D grid

Tags: image-processing, opencv, language-agnostic

Given a perfect grid and a few control points, how do I calculate the 'interpolatd' 2D grid - similar to Photoshop's functionality:

[image]

You move a control point and the image 'warps' to fit the new mesh.

What I'm trying to do is figure out the new position for each pixel. Any leads on what terms/keywords to look for/read up would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are a great many classes of 2D interpolants used in image processing, and their choice depends entirely on the application needs.

AFAIC the most common are based on [Radial Basis Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) . They define the interpolant as a linear combination of kernel functions located at the nodal points. A useful kernel function for smooth image deformation is the [Thin Plate Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline) .